# Nginx simple redirect old uri to new uri

Tags: nginx, redirect, seo, uri

I've got problems with simple SEO friendly redirect. Web page has changed and I'd like to redirect old uris to new ones. For example I'd like to redirect /contact to /contact.html

I've tried

```
location = /contact {
    rewrite ^ /contact.html permanent;
}
```

But it seems's that it doesn't work and Nginx keeps passing request to Zend front controller (PHP).

Here's my current configuration (without rewrites)

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name www.domain1.com domain1.com domain2.com www.domain2.com;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/domain1.error.log notice;

    root /home/domain1/www/public/;

    client_max_body_size 22M;

    #domain redirect
    if ($host != 'www.domain1.com' ) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain1.com/$1 permanent;
    }

    location / {
        index index.php;
    }

    # html cache static content
    location ~* \.(js|css|rdf|xml|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|jpeg|swf|eot|ttf|woff)$ {
        expires 30d;
    }

    rewrite /path1/(\w*)/\w*\.(\w*) /path2/$1.$2;

    #Zend front controller
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
        break;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9200;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/domain1/www/public$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV production;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a number of factors which could change the way you can fix this. Could you please provide your current server block for this host?

Comment: My current config is included

Answer (score 0):

I would do it easier and put it in the top of your / location

```
location / {
    rewrite  ^/contact$  /contact.html  permanent;

    ....
    ....
}
```

Comment: I tried but my config still redirects to index.php. I've included my current config in question